# how to make page scroll bottom and focus on iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have a webpage which has a huge banner image with some content. Below it, I have an iframe for a youtube video. The webpage is responsive, but when I open it on a mobile device the header is too big and the user needs to scroll down to view the video.

What I am trying to achieve is as the user opens the webpage on a mobile device, it should auto-scroll down to the iframe. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Could you please post some of your code as an example.

Answer (score 0):

You **will** need javascript for this.

`document.documentElement.clientHeight` returns the height of the client.

If this is not high enough, you should scroll them down:

`window.scrollTo(0, 500);`

So probably:

```
if(document.documentElement.clientHeight < 500) {
    window.scrollTo(0, 500);
}
```

The height depends on the size of your banner and location of your Iframe.

---

You could also try to, if you wish CSS only, move your banner below your Iframe if the height of the window is not enough.

You can use Media Queries for this:

```css
div div {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
}

div[blue] {
  background-color:blue;
} 

div[green] {
  background-color:green;
}

div[parent] {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse; 
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {

  div[parent] {
    flex-direction: column; 
  }

}
```

```html
<div parent>

  <div green>
  green
  </div>

  <div blue>
  blue
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.innerHeight` to detect whether the screen is too small, then use `window.scrollTo();` to scroll the page down to the iframe.

```js
maxHeight = 600;

function scrollIfMobile() {
  if (window.innerHeight < maxHeight) {
    var height = document.getElementById("iframe").offsetTop;
    window.scrollTo(0, height);
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 400px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="setTimeout(scrollIfMobile,1)">
  <div>
    Block<br />
  </div>
  <div id="iframe">
    Iframe<br />
  </div>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
  <div>
    ...
  </div>
</body>
```

[Here's a link to my example](https://b34f0ac1805d.netlify.com/). Try resizing the window.